# Programming with Python using Chrome OS

Tags: python, google-chrome-os

I just recently bought an Acer Chromebook 11 and I would like to do some Python programming on it. How do I run Python from a USB stick on an Acer Chromebook 11? (Also, I don't have access to wifi at the place I want to use it.)

Comment: Depends on the complexity. I'm not too familiar with the limitations of a Chromebook but you might be able to get away with using services like [CodeAnywhere](https://codeanywhere.com/)

Comment: I'll look into that. If it works, that means I don't have to install Java and have to carry around more stuff.

Comment: You can install Python using [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), although you will need to enable developer mode for this. For more information see [this asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64201789).

Answer (score 0):

On some chromebooks, like the one I'm using now, there is a Linux(beta) option in the options menu. Alternatively, you can use repl.it instead, although be aware that playing sound and using geocoder will work server-side instead, so the sound will not play, and the ip adress will be in New York.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click "Settings>Linux(beta)>Turn On".
2. Run "App Launcher>Terminal".
3. Type `python -v` or `python3 -v`.
4. If Python is not installed, download Python source file in https://www.python.org/downloads/source/.
5. Compile .tgz file.

If you have problems, try https://ide.goorm.io/. It is a web compiler for many programming languages, including Python. It has Linux command line too.